# Plotting all Childnodes with coordinates in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need help on my Capstone Project. I know some basics on retrieving data from Google Firebase, but I am stuck on a problem. My Firebase Structure looks like this:

```
BusNumber {
  9009 {
      Location: "10.134342,  124.8380294"
  }
  9010 {
      Location: "10.248606, 124.750047"
  } 
  9011 {
      Location: "10.035522, 124.982952"
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve all coordinates and plot them all on Google Maps. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "BusNumber" is your RootNode (Otherwise you have to adjust the initial reference before calling addChildEventListener)..

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            String title = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            LatLng position = getLatLngFromString(dataSnapshot.child("Location").getValue(String.class));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(position)
                    .title(title));
        }
        /* Other Overriden Methods Omitted */
    });
}


public static LatLng getLatLngFromString(String s) {
    String[] a = s.split("\\s*,\\s*");
    if (a.length > 2 || a[0].isEmpty() || a[1].isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("LatLng String is not valid!");
    }
    return new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(a[0]), Double.parseDouble(a[1]));
}
```

This should get you started. Obviously you would need to register/unregister the childeventlistener, handle the other methods in ChildEventListener etc..

I assume you have already setup a GoogleMap, if you have not, refer to the official guide: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker

Comment: Thanks for the help , ive Noticed you are also the one who helped me on Firebase Auth .. what do you mean by the register/unregister btw , im really new to Android and Firebase

Comment: Instead of calling `addChildEventListener(new ChildEve...)`, call `addChildEventListener(listener)`, where `listener` was defined somewhere as `ChildEventListener listener = new ChildEventListener...`. Then in onDestroy call something like `if listener not null, reference.removeEventListener(listener)`. Same thing with ValueEventListener

Comment: Do you have an email ? im confused already .. i have tried your answer but when i run the app the screen keep restarting over and over  and i dont see any marker

Comment: linxydev@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java to work with GeoLocation data. I think this is the easiest way to query data by location, etc.

Basically, you will get the result of your Firebase Query and use this code below:

```
geoFire.getLocation("firebase-hq", new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println(String.format("The location for key %s is [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
        } else {
            System.out.println(String.format("There is no location for key %s in GeoFire", key));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.err.println("There was an error getting the GeoFire location: " + databaseError);
    }
});
```

Hope that it helps you!